# synaptics driver not workin with new kernel?

Tags: 14.04, kernel, xorg, touchpad

after I upgraded from kernel 3.13.0-29 my synaptics driver seems to stopped working. basic touchpad functions still work (this includes moving cursor and clicking) but no right click nor middle click emulation neither scrolling works.
`synclient -l` gives error:

```
Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?

$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad                   id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳  USB OPTICAL MOUSE                        id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

also `xinput list-props 12`

```
Device 'PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad':

Device Enabled (142):   1
Coordinate Transformation Matrix (144): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
Device Accel Profile (265): 0
Device Accel Constant Deceleration (266):   1.000000
Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (267):   1.000000
Device Accel Velocity Scaling (268):    10.000000
Device Product ID (261):    2, 1
Device Node (262):  "/dev/input/event4"
Evdev Axis Inversion (269): 0, 0
Evdev Axes Swap (271):  0
Axis Labels (272):  "Rel X" (152), "Rel Y" (153)
Button Labels (273):    "Button Left" (145), "Button Middle" (146), "Button Right" (147), "Button Wheel Up" (148), "Button Wheel Down" (149)
Evdev Middle Button Emulation (274):    0
Evdev Middle Button Timeout (275):  50
Evdev Third Button Emulation (276): 0
Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (277): 1000
Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (278):  3
Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (279):   20
Evdev Wheel Emulation (280):    0
Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (281):   0, 0, 4, 5
Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (282):    10
Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (283):    200
Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (284): 4
Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (285):  0
```

so everything looks normal. on the other hand `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep syna` gives nothing, but `cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep Syn` gives reasonable output:

```
[    29.173] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/event4)
[    29.173] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Applying InputClass "evdev pointer catchall"
[    29.173] (II) Using input driver 'evdev' for 'PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[    29.173] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: always reports core events
[    29.173] (**) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Device: "/dev/input/event4"
[    29.173] (--) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Vendor 0x2 Product 0x1
[    29.173] (--) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found 3 mouse buttons
[    29.173] (--) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found relative axes
[    29.173] (--) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Found x and y relative axes
[    29.173] (II) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: Configuring as mouse
[    29.173] (**) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: YAxisMapping: buttons 4 and 5
[    29.173] (**) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: EmulateWheelButton: 4, EmulateWheelInertia: 10, EmulateWheelTimeout: 200
[    29.173] (II) XINPUT: Adding extended input device "PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad" (type: MOUSE, id 12)
[    29.173] (II) evdev: PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: initialized for relative axes.
[    29.173] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) keeping acceleration scheme 1
[    29.173] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration profile 0
[    29.173] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration factor: 2.000
[    29.173] (**) PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad: (accel) acceleration threshold: 4
[    29.173] (II) config/udev: Adding input device PS/2 Synaptics TouchPad (/dev/input/mouse0)
```

I have tried adding entry to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` but it did not work. 
When I boot using kernel  3.13.0-29 everything works. With any newer kernel - problems.
Any idea on how to fix/debug it?

cheers!

Comment: Try to fingers tap for right-click

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing like that works. Running `evtest` as root indicates that no events other than left click, right click and moving cursor  are detected